# The interworking of TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

`EditText` extends `TextView` and all it does is to set it to be editable so I've been reading the source code of [android.widget.TextView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/TextView.java) trying to figure out how `EditText` works.

I cant figure out how the editing mechanism works, the string is saved in `mText`, when a users clicks somewhere on the view it knows where in the string it is (cursor position) and then inserts/removes text at that position. I can't seem to find that part of the code that handles that, the insertion at a specific position. the link between the text on display and mText. If you know how that works exactly I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: If you want to figure out how `EditText` works, I'd expect the source code for `EditText` to be more enlightening than the only looking at the base class `TextView`...

Comment: As I wrote in the question, it's all inside TextView, EditText is a very small class that extends TextView and overrides getDefaultEditable() to return true, which makes it editable.

Comment: A quick browse showed a field called "mInputMethodState" which seems to deal with modifying the text. Maybe looking at how that works will help? It might better worth your time though to just ask a google dev on the android forums: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-developers.